# What do you call a person who uses a boomerang?

Tags: single-word-requests

You can say a person good at archery is a highly skilled archer. A person who is good with a boomerang is a _______?

Comment: Boomernager? 
Boomerangee?

Answer (score 1):

The Boomerang Association of Australia just calls them *boomerang throwers*:

> Despite the wind, he won the competition, as well as the WA Championships the week before, which places him firmly by reputation as the best boomerang thrower Australia has.
>   [- "Australian Competitions 2016 Special Bulletin Photo Edition", Boomerang Association of Australia](http://boomerang.org.au/wp/australian-competitions-2016-special-bulletin-photo-edition/)

It also uses the term *master boomerang thrower*:

> The Australian master boomerang thrower Rob Croll won the competition at his home ground at Lewis Park in Wantirna South 4th October, followed by his fellow Victorian Dave Richardson and South Australian Simon Bollen.
>   [- "Victorian Mini-Competition Results 2015", Boomerang Association of Australia](http://boomerang.org.au/wp/victorian-mini-competition-results-2015/)